# Weekly atmospheric or oceanic oscillation within Arctic region

Tags: atmosphere, ocean, arctic

I'm in the middle of writing my Master's thesis. I've analyzed Ocean Bottom Pressure (OBP) signals derived from observations by the GRACE satellites.These observations are able to reproduce sub-monthly OBP variability which was pre-GRACE not possible.

I performed a DFT on the available data and found within the arctic region in winter a strong mode with a period length of 7-8 days.

Most of these sub-monthly OBP oscillations can be explained by atmospheric forcing or wind stress forcing and i was wondering if anyone knows any atmospheric oscillations with that period length and
in that region?

Comment: Have you looked at any correlation with the Arctic Oscillation? That is the go-to index for arctic weather. 

Have you compared it to the characteristic lengths of Rossby Waves?

Comment: Also, the fact that this is in the arctic in winter is also interesting. Have you considered the rate at which there is increasing sunlight?

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus thank you for your comment. The problem with the Arctic Oscillation Index is that it is only available as monthly means. So there is no way to know the impact on these short timescales. Correct me if i'm wrong but i only found AOI data here http://goo.gl/fEVdS8.

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus forget what i wrote. I found the daily AO exports and will look into it. i'll write about the results.

Comment: Can You clarify what is the actual region and if You look at the average of some region or point data?